# How to pass values to Angular index.html from spring security success handler

Tags: spring, angular

How can I pass values (userName, language_code etc) to my Angular ´index.html´ from my spring security success handler?

I'm currently using this code to load the angular application from server:

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/admin/index.html");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are multiple ways to go about this. Considering you are building a Single Page Application:

1. You can actually send an Ajax GET user details request from angular to fetch the details at the first load of Angular app
2. You can set a simple cookie in response before sending a redirect call like below and read its value from your frontend using JS

> response.addCookie("details",userName+":"+languageCode)

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend the way you are using Standard Spring Security authentication with Angular. The best option is to use Spring Security OAuth2/JWT to enable authentication from Angular.

But you can send the `userName` and `language_code` as Query String when redirecting like following

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/admin/index.html?userName="+userName+"&language_code=en");
```

And those query strings in Angular as following

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

....

export class YourComponent {

    userName: string;

    langCode: string;

    constructor(
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ) { }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams =>
       this.userName = queryParams['userName'];
       this.langCode = queryParams['language_code'];
     );
   }

}
```

Comment: The above `queryParams` approach results in the following error : `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'index.html'`